# CSS JS animate image along path and make dashes afterwards

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg

I would like to animate an image on a path and show the route of the object (e.g a plane flying over a map). It should look like on this image:

[image: plane on map]

But the dashes should apply after the object has reached the position, so the dashes were shown after the object.

I have tried multiple times, but I can do only once. Dash animation or plane on path . Does someone knows a solution.

Comment: Please share what have you tried.

Comment: make image inline

Answer (score 12):

1. animate a mask over the dashed path
2. move the plane along the same path

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     version="1.1" height="200" width="400">
  <defs>
    <path id="basePath" d="M 50,150 A 280 500 0 0 1 350,150" />
    <mask id="mask">
      <use xlink:href="#basePath" stroke-width="3" stroke="white"
           stroke-dasharray="1000,0" fill="none">
        <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" from="0,348.5" to="348.5,0"
            begin="0s" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
      </use>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <circle r="4" cx="50" cy="150" fill="grey" />
  <circle r="4" cx="350" cy="150" fill="grey" />
  <use xlink:href="#basePath" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="10"
       stroke="grey" fill="none" mask="url(#mask)"/>
  <path d="M 27,3 H 21 L 13,15 H 9 L 12,3 H 5 L 3,7 H -1 L 1,0 -1,-7 H 3 L 5,-3 H 12 L 9,-15 H 13 L 21,-3 H 27 C 33,-3 33,3 27,3 Z"
       fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="1.5">
    <animateMotion rotate="auto" begin="0s" dur="5s" fill="freeze">
      <mpath xlink:href="#basePath"/>
    </animateMotion>
  </path>
</svg>
```

The main thing to do is to calculate the length of the path, so you can set the stroke-dasharray values for the mask animation such that they keep pace with the animated plane. You can get that length in Javascript with

```
document.querySelector('#basePath').getTotalLength()
```